# net use failed while doing it manually in the explorer OK

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, network-shares

My `net use` would fail with this:

```
C:> net use W: \\remote.share.server\path
System error 1396 has occurred.

The target account name is incorrect.
```

while doing it manually in the explorer OK.

Based on the *"The target account name is incorrect"* message, I guess that doing it manually in the explorer would negotiate a proper account to do the connection, as my company has at least three or five domains, and we have separated accounts for them. I.e., `net use` would use my default account and it is not good for my `\\remote.share.server\path`.

But all these are my guessing and I need a solution so that I don't need to do it manually in the explorer again and again, as the network map goes disconnected often. Thx.

Comment: You should try to specify the domain and the username in that command.

Comment: I know @Ramhound, but my company has at least three or five domains and we have separated accounts for them. How can I know what exactly the domain and the username I should use?

Comment: You don't know what domains you have usernames to? Have you asked your IT Administrator for assistance? I mean at the simplest levels, what domain is the machine that you are accessing, connect to? It would be extremely odd for a single machine to be connected to multiple separate active directory domains at once.  So ask your IT Administrator, what active directory domain is `remote.share.server` connected to, then authenticate to that domain.

Comment: I know in a perfect world, things would work like that @Ramhound but in reality, the ugly truth of my situation/my company, is that the `remote.share.server` has just moved from an old domain to a new domain, of which my account in that domain is still not working yet, I've also lost the RDP access to that server after the move, yet I'm able to establish net share manually in the explorer. The turn-around time of IT department is in week. Why I simply cannot get the info I need from net use or active directory, I don't understand why it is so hard to get such info for end user like me.